# Can a Form be used as a user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I need to make a UserControl that can be used for multiple projects. But it needs to be a Form so the user can just add a reference to the library and call the form.

I've seen third party companies like Telerik and DevExpress use custom forms that can be added to a project.

How would I accomplish this? I've been looking through SO and various posts from Google, but have not been successful in my searches.

*EDIT* I was assuming it had to be a UserControl for some reason. But it doesn't. I took the suggestion of just adding a form and calling it from that namespace. Works exactly as needed. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Being able to just add reference and use something does not require the something to be a form. Please clarify.

Comment: Have you thought about just creating the custom user control and adding it to a form? Not sure if that's exactly what you need.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is not a user control. Do you wish to develop some kind of control you can just add and use in any project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the form in your library, make it public, and you can call it from anywhere.

Methods to create and call form are:

```
YourFormClassName FormForUser = new YourFormClassName();
FormForUser.Show();
FormForUser.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: There's really no mistery in that, unless you want the form to be really a user control and not a common form to be called.

Comment: A dialog is rather fundamentally different from a user control.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand.  If I do, then it's straight forward.

1. Add a project (ProjectWithReusedForm) to your solution that contains the form to be reused.
2. Add a reference to ProjectWithReusedForm in the second project where you want to use the form
3. Add a 'using ProjectWithReusedFormNamespace' to the code where you want to use the form

You then can add the statement ReusedForm myForm = new ReusedForm();

Answer (score 0):

Just Create form with all controls. and create empty user control

Ex:

do this code inside usercontrol constructor after initialize function

```
dim obja as new RegForm()
obja.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
obja.Visible = true
obja.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Full
me.Controls.Add(obja)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `BaseForm` (either add it into a project directly by adding `.cs` file or reference something compiled - class library to example). Then just **add a new form** to a project

```
namespace MySolution
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

and chang `Form` to `BaseForm`

```
    public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful here.  Your tag lists winforms, so I am assuming you are using .net and UserControls.  Winforms only allows a single form per page.  You can add multiple UserControls to a page.  If you go with the base form route, the programmer will have to add everything else to your base page.  UserControls will offer a little more flexibility in that they can be added to an existing page.